# Saving Shapefile - Zero Features Error

Tags: qgis, shapefile, features, epsg

I am using QGIS 3.02. I opened a GDB file in QGIS and saved it as a shapefile in EPSG: 4326. Now I want to save it in EPSG: 2264 but I am running into an issue. Every time I save it as EPSG: 2264 the features disappear - QGIS produces a layer with zero features, and nothing is visible on the map.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot produce the same issue in QGIS 3.0.1. I can save the data properly in EPSG: 2264  and displaying them without problem.

I tested a point shapefile with EPSG: 4326 and saved it as EPSG: 2264 successfully as you can see below:

[image]

Try to check the topology of the original data. It may have some topological errors.

Comment: I think I've found the issue - QGIS is reading the GBD file with an invalid projection. Is that a common issue when opening GBD files in QGIS?

Comment: I am not sure about that, without seeing the data it is difficult to judge if it is a problem of reading GDB or something else.